# How to make your followers craft?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So following on from this question [How can I find my followers skills and stats](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36380/how-can-i-find-my-followers-skills-and-stats) I've found that Sven is good at some craft skills, namely Alchemy, Smithing and Enchanting.

How do you get them to craft, or control it? I know you can talk to them and ask "I'd like you to do something." to get into command mode and point them at a workbench for example, but how can you control what they make?

I've pointed Sven at the forge and he's come back with nothing. Perhaps I need to load him up with materials?

Comment: yes try giving him materials to use first.

Comment: But if I give him Iron Ingots and Leather Strips x3, will he make 3 daggers or 1 iron guantlets and 1 iron dagger?

Comment: I was suggesting that you test it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I loaded Lydia up with some Iron Ingots and Leather Strips, enough to make several different types of item. Then I commanded her to use the forge. I didn't get a crafting menu or any means of commanding her to craft a specific item.

She used the forge for a while (carried out all the various crafting animations), I left her at it for five minutes realtime and checked her inventory. She still had all the ingots and leather strips I gave her, and she hadn't crafted any items, despite having appeared to have been crafting for a long time.

So at least for Lydia it seems that it's not possible to craft items.

Answer (score 1):

IT is not possible to have them craft items for you, their skills are simply to build their 'character' that they have skills.

I also tried giving Lydia some ingredients, they are mostly useful for carrying them, they won't craft with them.

On a different topic tho, they will use-up charges on magic items, so keep that in mind if you stick stuff in their inventory you don't want used ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's a mod called **Followers can craft** and here's how it's done:

> -With this mod your followers can craft like the player character and will level there skills like he does. 
>   This means they will create/temper weapons and armor, enchant/disenchant items, make potions and even cook for you.
>
> -They will also taste ingredients for you and grant you Green Thump and Soul Squeezer if they reach the required skill level.
>
> -Crafting:
>
> -Ask your follower to do you a favor (the "I need you to do something" dialog line) and point him/her to a workplace (i.e. Workbench, Forge, Enchanter). He/she will then start to craft you what ever you want using the vanilla crafting menu.
>   Your followers will level there skills like the player character does and take all perks that improve there work (i.e. the 5 enchanter perks) when they reach the required skill level.