# Do followers have skill levels and level similar to my characters?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was helping Vilkas go to the temple and on our way I made a pitstop at a dungeon.
Inside the dungeon he would get hit only once and be down on the floor with barely any health...

So, I'm curious if followers have levels and if so how to do you check it and get them leveled?

Generally I don't take a follower because they ruin my sneak attack, don't do anything useful or end up getting killed because they stand right in front of me.

If there is a similar question on here please direct me..I've searched but haven't been able to find anything useful as of yet.

Comment: I read this from http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers: "If you have an attachment to a certain follower and wish to continue to use them after they have become obsolete, you can use the Wabbajack to force their stats to be updated."  I'm going to try it when I get the Wabbajack.

Comment: This duplicates main parts of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/36864/54123).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Followers have stats just like the player in skills and health.  Those values are static and are set the first time you enter/load the zone that they are in.  There are also maximum level caps for followers should your level be higher than that the first time you encounter them.

For example, most people meet Lydia very early on and she'll end up being locked in with 100 health and skills in the 20s, so she won't be as effective as Jordis (the housecarl you get in Solitude) whom you'll usually meet much later on since the house costs 25k gold to purchase.

If you are on the PC, there is a way to force an NPC to level up by resetting them:

1. First, remove all the gear from the follower (at least the ones that you want to keep).
2. Walk up to them, be as close as possible, open the console with the ~ key
3. Click on your follower.  When you do so, a string will appear at the top of your console that represents your follower's reference ID.
4. On your console, type disable, then follow it up with enable

After this, your companion will be 'reset' to match what your current level is.  Their health and skills should be improved.

Finally, keep in mind that all followers fall under a general category: warrior, thief, or mage.  Lydia, for example, is a warrior and will never gain a sneak skill above 15 no matter what level you meet her at.

Comment: Sweet! I didn't know they were static, that makes a lot of sense. Going to try that with the console. ty

Comment: @Avien no problem.  If you want to find a follower with a specific skill set, repeat steps 1-3 and use the command getav [insert skill/stat] to see what the actual value is.  For example, getav health

Comment: Ok, thanks again. That will definitely be useful :)

Comment: Yes, followers DO have levels.

Comment: uesp.net disagrees - http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers - and links to a detailed spreadsheet with the max level for each follower

Comment: Lydia has the same stats than before using the console, can it be that not much changes if you are levl 29 only

Comment: @shoran that depends on what level you were when you first obtained her.  The change in hp and skills such as one handed should be very obvious

Comment: are followers stats locked in when you first encounter the character, or when they become an actually follower?  For instance, I've met jzargo in game, but he is not yet a follower.  Are his stats already locked?

Comment: @frankschwieterman they become locked in when you first load the zone that they are in.

Comment: @spartacus thanks, it sounds like the game changed as of 1.6 and characters now level with you.  I play on xbox though, so I'm not sure how to verify.  One thing I noticed is that it seemed like even Esbern will level with you.  I was keeping him awhile to have many companions.  At first he was casting frost astronauch, then when I hit 39 or 40 he started casting storm astronauch.

Comment: I wonder if followers still have the level 30 limits?  I don't know how to check really.

Comment: is this still correct? i am reading something of a patch 1.6

Answer (score 5):

From the UESP wiki's "[Skyim Followers - Follower Stats](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers#Follower_Stats)" article:

> A follower levels up according to the PC's level up to the follower's maximum level (which varies for each). With few exceptions, each follower has a maximum level, and a specific set of primary skills, which are dictated by their [class](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Classes).
>
> Prior to [patch 1.6](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch#Version_1.6), a follower's skills, health, and other stats were set when they were first spawned (which is typically when you enter their starting cell, become a Thane, and so on) and would not increase as their level increased. Prior to the fixing of this failure of stats to update with patch 1.6, players could update a non-essential follower's stats so they would increase based on their current level by using the Wabbajack to polymorph them into another creature, after which their stats would update upon recovering their original form. Players of the PC version could also use certain console commands to fix any follower's inability to update their stats with each level.

So in most cases, leveling up the player character will also make your follower level up, (the maximum and by how much, will depend on the [specific follower](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers) and their [NPC class](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Classes)).

Answer (score 3):

While you can't change the archetype of a follower you can modify their skills. If you are a assassin/thief type character and you still want Lydia to sneak around with you. Open console, click on Lydia, type "forceav sneak 100" this will set her sneak skill to 100.

Comment: +1 thanks, Lydia keeps bothering me that she doesn't sneak and I keep getting discovered.

Answer (score 1):

Every follower has a certain set of skills from the start. Since Skyrim patch 1.6, the level of followers scales with your level even after you met them the first time (although most followers have a maximum). You can find the professions and maximum levels of every follower at the [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers) and [TES](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Followers_(Skyrim)#Followers) wikis.

There is a mod named **Ask Follower Skills** ([Nexus Mods](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/10675) / [Steam Workshop](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=13119))
to check out the current level and the skills of your follower.

When you enable this mod, save a game, and load it again, then you can ask the follower: "*What can you do?*", and this will give the stats like this (Faendal as an example):
[image: Skills/Levels for Faendal]

Comment: That mod was not updated since November 2012, which means it wasn't updated to 1.9. Also, the mod descriptions states that it was rolled into Big Dialogue Overhaul, which itself is now called [Ultimate Follower Overhaul](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/14037/?).

Comment: All of that is correct, but I don't see why that is relevant. I have this mod working fine with current skyrim (steam) and UFO does include a bad/old version of this (if it is still like in the screenshots) and lots of stuff I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

House yarls level up thmore you use them. But not other followers such as one you would find in a tavern. So if you use a specific character more then they will get stronger. But they do have limits, such as Lydia. She can level up in warrior skills but not much in magic or stealth.