# Is it possible to find out what level your follower is on?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Also, is it possible to level them up? Or do they level up just like me by fighting and increasing their skills?

Comment: There is also a mod which fixes all the follower problems. It makes the followers level up with you. POWER OF MODS!

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/36380/54123).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find my followers skills and stats?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36380/how-can-i-find-my-followers-skills-and-stats)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I don't think that this is a dupe of [How can I find my followers skills and stats?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/36380/4797) This one's asking about the level, while the other one is asking about skills and stats. While answers with mod solutions may be the same for the two questions, answers recommending non-mod solutions won't be. (They have different console commands, for example.)

Comment: @galacticninja Level *is* a stat, though. All of the 'answers' on this question that suggest mods are mods that list follower stats.The accepted answer doesn't actually explain how to see the follower's current level except at the very bottom; the rest is about how to level them up. (Besides, the OP is on PS3 and can't use console commands.)

Comment: This is quite a different question, even if the answers have the potential to overlap. The additional questions differentiate it even more.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas  Aside from the question titles, the OPs of both questions have other related questions in the question bodies that are different and do not overlap with each other. That's probably why the OP of this question accepted the currently accepted answer - because it answers the questions in the body (including how to level followers up). Answers shouldn't dictate whether two questions are duplicates. Mods in the answers here that also answer the other question don't make this question a dupe of the other one.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas RE: 'OP is on PS3 and can't use console commands.' Please see this meta post about that: [Questions where OP has mentioned he/she is using a specific platform: how to answer, how to tag and when to close as exact duplicate?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5488/4797)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are locked at the level on which you hired them, and will not continue to level up as you do.

To set them on your current level(should be higher) you can:

- use console commands on the PC ("disable" then "enable" the character
  while they are not in your party.
- use [Wabbajack](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Wabbajack) to turn them into a mudcrab/goat/etc, then rehire them
  when they change back.

This resets their stats to the current player level, and also does not appear to reset their inventory or quest scripting (although you will need to take an item from their inventory and put it back to get them to re-equip any non-default equipment you've given them). However, it has no effect if they are currently in your party. Essential characters can not be transformed, therefore essential followers can not reset their stats unless using console commands.

There are a couple very specific occasions in which certain Followers will level up due to scripted events in quests.

Note that most of followers can reach max lvl 30 so updating them past this level would be useless.

For those on PC check out `getlevel` and `setlevel` console commands.

Comment: I have a PS3, not a PC. What then??

Comment: @David The Wabbajack should still work on the PS3.

Comment: How do I get it?

Comment: Investigate a man called Dervenin. He can be found walking around the streets near the Bards College.He will than lead you to quest chain to get the wabbajack.

Comment: Will they automatically change back or do I have to do something?? :)

Comment: yes it is automatic,but make sure before you use it to get companion out from your party...tell them to go home or stop following you,be quick and use it before they really leave.

Comment: @David You get the [Wabbajack][1] from from the [Mind of Madness][2] quest in Solitude.


  [1]: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Wabbajack_%28Skyrim%29
  [2]: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Mind_of_Madness

Comment: Follower levels are not locked anymore after Patch 1.6. They level with you up to their maximum level.

Answer (score 2):

The **[UFO - Ultimate Follower Overhaul](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/14037)** mod allows you to view your follower's level, specific skill levels and other stats (through a conversation option):

[image: UFO Character Sheet]

Answer (score 1):

There is a mod named **Ask Follower Skills** ([Nexus](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/10675)/[Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=13119))
to check out the current level and the skills of your follower.

When you enable this mod, save a game and load it again. You can then ask the follower: *What can you do?* and this will give the stats like this (Faendal as an example):
[image: Skills/Levels for Faendal]

Since Skyrim patch 1.6 the level of followers scales with your level even after you met them the first time (although most followers have a maximum).
You can find the professions and maximum levels of every follower at the [UESP](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers) and [The Elder Scrolls](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Follower_%28Skyrim%29#Followers) wikis.